# Inflation as an independent variable

Tags: regression, linear-model, finance

Assume a model like this, basically explaining stock market returns with a bunch of stuff:

```
stockReturn(t) ~ bondReturn(t) + moneyMarketReturn(t) + inflation(t) + somethingElse(t)
```

1) Does using inflation as an independent variable bring any significant problems?

2) Should the results differ from using real returns instead, in this case using the inflation to calculate real stock, bond, and money market returns (assuming that the somethingElse is a non-economic variable). What would affect the difference?

So here we would do this for the stock, bond, and money market returns to get the real returns:

```
realReturn(t) = ( 1 + return(t) )/( 1 + inflation(t) ) - 1
```

and then drop inflation from the model.

Comment: It may not be useful to use inflation as a determinant of the the stock return. A commonsense would suggest that money market return takes it into.

Comment: I don't see any particular problems it would raise. But there are the *usual* problems. E.g. you'd have to check collinearity.

Comment: This is not the statistical question. This is the question from quant finance or macroeconomics area. It is not possible to answer it from pure statistical point of view, trust me.

Comment: @Aksakal The first question might be more from the finance field. But what about the other one, I think that should be a bit more statistical.

Comment: @Roope, no, there's economic theory around these things. He should post these questions in quant finance SE.